# insert magento category not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php

when i try to insert  new category  in database no error appear and no category inserted
here is my code what is wrong

> not that the new categories are parent not child
>
> ---
>
> $cat_arr  have some categories

```
try{
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                foreach ($cat_arr as $cat ) {


                        $category->setName($cat['shortName']);
                        $category->setUrlKey($cat['localizedId']);
                        $category->setIsActive(1);
                        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
                        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
                        $category->setDescription($cat['name']);

                        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                        $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
                        // $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
                        // $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());

                        $category->save();
                    }
                    } catch(Exception $e) {
                        var_dump($e);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue1:

```
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); code inside for
loop
```

**Issue2:**

```
check list of attribute which is  in  category using
below code

 foreach ($category->getAttributes() as $attribute) 
}
```

Comment: `code`
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); code inside for
loop

you mean that i should put it inside loop ??

Comment: Yea,,,.............